# Reg Expression for number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I need to have textarea (or input) that allows negative sign, percentage sign and decimal number. i.e. 3000, -3.5, 50%, -50.5% - all valid.
I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/f1w38jw0/10/)  and adjust the regex to

```
/^[\-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*[%]{0,1}$/
```

My problem is I cannot add negative sign before I enter a number.

My code is:

```js
$(function() {
  var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

  $("textarea.aaa").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
  }).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^[\-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*[%]{0,1}$/;

    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
      this.value = pastValue;
      this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
      this.selectionEnd = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="myText" class="aaa" /></textarea>
```

Comment: Try [`/^-?(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*%?)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/uL4rY5/1). Perhaps, a better one will be `/^-?(?:[0-9]*(?:\.(?:[0-9]+%?)?)?)?$/`

Answer (score 2):

The regex used in snippet will allow minus sign as well. User can add minus sign only once in the beginning. You can use it on keydown events as well no need to use it onsubmit only. Please check the snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(function() {
  var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

  $("textarea.aaa").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
  }).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^-?\d*\.?\d{0,6}$/;

    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
      this.value = pastValue;
      this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
      this.selectionEnd = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="myText" class="aaa" /></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your regex makes it compulsory to have at least one digit, so that when you type `-` it fails.

To make it work, make the numeric part optional, together with making the `-` optional as well (the `-?` syntax):

```
var regex = /^-?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*%?)?$/;
//            ^^
//              ^                 ^^
```

Note the problem now is that a string consisting in just `-` will pass the regex.

All together:

```js
$(function() {
  var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

  $("textarea.aaa").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
  }).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^-?(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*%?)?$/;

    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
      this.value = pastValue;
      this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
      this.selectionEnd = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="myText" class="aaa" /></textarea>
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what? I was posting an answer. If you want to post comments, that is perfectly fine, but this shouldn't mean that anybody else can post an answer in the meanwhile.

Comment: So I need to add a validation onsubmit

Comment: @SarahO. yes, this sounds like the most robust way: one validation for input and one for the submit. And always, of course, do add some validation in the back-end, since any piece of front-end can be tricked.